# need FMVC codec for ubuntu 14.04v

Tags: gpu-driver

Am using ubuntu 14.04, now i got a problem with videos,when am trying to play them, its asking for FMVC codec, but i tried to install FMVC codec, it do not support. can you please find me the way to play those videos on my system

Comment: well what do you mean by **those videos** can you tell what videos exactly? I mean their format at least. And what is the player you use?

Answer (score 0):

Those type files can only be decoded in linux by using a 32 bit mplayer & w32codecs. Info here if you can satisfy the above.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2030108